# jQuery validation - getting undefined element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation script but I am not able to display validation message to my div with `errorPlacement`. After using `console.log(element);` I am getting `undefined` error.

**I HTML Work:**

```
<form id="frmSubmitListing" method="post" action="#">
    <ul id="step1">
        <li>
           <select name="year" id="year" class="selectpicker">
                <option value="">Year</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    <span id="yearError" class="requ" style="display: none;"></span>
        <input type="button" name="saleBottomStep1" id="saleBottomStep1" value="step1">
    </ul>

    <ul id="step2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="rooms" value="">
        <span id="roomsError" class="requ" style="display: none;"></span>
        <input type="button" name="saleBottomStep2" id="saleBottomStep2" value="step2" />
    </ul>
</form>
```

**My Validation Work:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').selectpicker();
    $("#frmSubmitListing").validate({
        //onkeyup: false,
        //onfocusout: false,
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
        year: {
            required: true
        }
        },
        messages: {
        "year": {
            required: "Required field"
        }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr("name") == "year") {
            $('#yearError').text(error.text()).show();  
        }
        }
    });
    });

    // Clear validation error
    $("#year").change(function () {
    if ($("#year").valid() == true) {
        $('#yearError').hide();
    }
    });

    //  Submit first step if no error found
    $('#saleBottomStep1').click(function () {
    // If form is valid then move to second step
        if ($("#frmSubmitListing").valid()) {
        $('#step1').hide();
        $('#step2').show();     
        }
    });

    //  Submit second step if no error found
    $('#saleBottomStep2').click(function () {
    // If form is valid then move to third step
    $("input[name*=rooms]").rules( "add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
        required: "Required field"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log(element);
        if(this.attr( "name" )== "rooms") {
            $('#roomsError').text(error.text()).show();    
        }
        }
    });
    });
});
```

My JSFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/53/

I will haapy If you support me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: please create jsFiddle.Then we will be able to solve ur question Correctly .

Comment: I am creating jsFiddle for you.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Here is my JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/53/

Comment: Your fiddle works like butter , what else is expected , Please explain here.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Ohh really. I have checked fiddle and it's working. So no need to open this question.

Comment: Its basically SAME fiddle  u provided , check ur question , 3rd last line ,  `My JSFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/53/`  :) :)

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird I have checked fiddle but in my code I have only two step which I also mentioned in my question. I did not set step 3 button :)

Comment: Then who added jsfiddle in Your question?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Question and JSFiddle that I have updated on my question but that time my code was not working. I am going to close this question.

Comment: The `.rules()` method is only for dynamically manipulating rules... you **cannot** put anything else inside.  In other words, the `errorPlacement` callback can only be inside the `.validate()` method and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with accessing tags.Try the following (U didnt test it)

```
        if(this.attr( "name" )== "rooms") {
            jQuery('#roomsError').text(error.text()).show();    
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jQuery("#formName").validate({` before it.

```
    jQuery("#formName").validate({


jQuery("input[name*=rooms]").rules( "add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Required field"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                console.log(element);
                if(this.jQuery.attr("name") == "rooms") {
                    jQuery('#roomsError').text(error.text()).show();    
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for supporting me. I have tried your code but getting error in logic. I have updated my question so can check once again and let me where I am wrong.

Comment: did u try using  `"input[name^=rooms]")` ??

Comment: Hi I have update my question with my code and this is my JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/53/

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var validate=$("formid").validate({

// Specify the validation rules
    rules:
{
    "rooms": "required"
},


 messages:
{

    "rooms": "Required field"
    },


submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is another way to show validation messages. Once you see the message you can manipulate its css to show it in appropriate position.